# Удаленное подключение к ubuntu server 22.04 имеющим 2 сетевые карты

Tags: putty

Запустил ubuntu server на ВМ с 2 сетевыми картами. Одна подключена в режиме моста, другая смотрив в ЛС. Изначально в /etc/netplan/*.yaml прописана одна сетвая карта. ifconfig тоже видит одну сетевую карту. В таком режиме putty подключаеться нормально с адресом ip выданным маршрутизатором.
Когда в netplan ввожу 2 сетвую карту со статическим ip адресом (эта та, что смотрит в ЛС) putty не запускаеться. Пишет "Connection timeout". На машине работает bind сервер, dhcp сервер. все настройки по мануалам прописаны правильно. dhcp сервер работает. Putty не подключаеться только при вводе в netplan сетевой карты со статическим адресом. В чем может быть проблума? Файрвол отключен. Проброс портов черз соединение NAT тоже не помогает.

Comment: Подсети пересекаются

Comment: Подсеть сетевухи смотрящая в ЛС с подсетью сетевухи смотрящую в инет? Как это можно исправить? Просто изменить подсеть или есть еще способы? Дело в том, что dhcp почему то не запустился с подсетью 192.168.0.0. Он запустился с 192.168.1.1. И в инет карта работает на той же подсети.